# Error in basic HelloWorld App. in Java Spark

Tags: slf4j, spark-framework

I tried to write a very basic HelloWorld-example with the Spark Java Framework
and it always gives me the same long error-code. I'm using Intellij IDEA.

Application.java :

```
import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import static spark.Spark.get;
import static spark.Spark.staticFileLocation;

    public class AppService {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            staticFileLocation("/public");
            get("/login", AppService::helloworld);
        }

    public static String helloworld(Request req, Response res) {
        return "Hello, World?";
    }
}
```

My Error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton(StaticLoggerBinder.java:53)
>       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:299)
>       at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
>       at org.apache.log4j.Category.(Category.java:57)
>       at org.apache.log4j.Logger.(Logger.java:37)
>       at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
>       at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
>       (and this repeats with very little alterations in about 1029 lines)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Thanks in advance!

Color

Comment: you forget `)` in get function

Comment: That´s true but that happened when copying the code in here.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it tho, by importing the right Libraries ^^